# Replace all characters in a regex match with the same character in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a regex to replace a certain pattern with a certain string, where the string is built dynamically by repeating a certain character as many times as there are characters in the match.

For example, say I have the following substitution command:

```
%s/hello/-----/g
```

However, I would like to do something like this instead:

```
%s/hello/-{5}/g
```

where the non-existing notation `-{5}` would stand for the dash character repeated five times.

Is there a way to do this?

Ultimately, I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
%s/(hello)*/-{\=strlen(\0)}/g
```

which would replace any instance of a string of only `hello`s with the string consisting of the dash character repeated the number of times equal to the length of the matched string.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
%s/\v(hello)*/\=repeat('-',strlen(submatch(0)))/g
```

Comment: Works! Thanks. Do you know where I can find all available functions (like strlen and repeat)?

Comment: Or `function-list`. Sometimes it's more handy.

Comment: To read more about it, use `:help sub-replace-special` and `:help sub-replace-expression`

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to using the `:substitute` command (the usage of
which is already covered in @Peter’s answer), I can suggest automating
the editing commands for performing the replacement by means of
a self-referring macro.

A straightforward way of overwriting occurrences of the search pattern
with a certain character by hand would the following sequence of
Normal-mode commands.

1. Search for the start of the next occurrence.

   ```
   /\(hello\)\+
   ```
2. Select matching text till the end.

   ```
   v//e
   ```
3. Replace selected text.

   ```
   r-
   ```
4. Repeat from step 1.

Thus, to automate this routine, one can run the command

```
:let[@/,@s]=['\(hello\)\+',"//\rv//e\rr-@s"]
```

and execute the contents of that `s` register starting from the
beginning of the buffer (or anther appropriate location) by

```
gg@s
```