# vim: replace n strings with another strings

Tags: vim

After reading [Vim regex replace with n characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338794/vim-regex-replace-with-n-characters), I've known how to replace tabs by spaces:

```
:%s/^\v(\t)*/\=repeat(repeat(' ',4),strlen(submatch(0)))/g
```

The command above allows me to replace n tabs at the beginning of each line with n four-spaces.

Now I want to inverse it: replace n four-spaces with n tabs at the beginning of each line, I think the command should be `:%s/^\v(    )*/\=repeat("\t",strlen(submatch(0)))/g`, but it doesn't work: if there is one four-space, it will be replaced by four tabs (but I want to make it only one tab) after executing the command.

Besides, is it possible to get the length of tab of vim so that I can make the command as below?

```
:%s/^\v(\t)*/\=repeat(repeat(' ',getSizeOfTab()),strlen(submatch(0)))/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of an option in Vimscript by prepending `&`. So, the size of tab is `&tabstop`, or `&ts`. There's also `&softtabstop` (`&sts`), pick which one you actually care about.

Whereas you needed to multiply the number of spaces with size of tab, you need to *divide* the number of tabs. Then there's the remainder to take care of. So, first set your `tabstop`:

```
:set ts=4
```

Then you can convert from tabs to spaces and from spaces to tabs like this:

```
:%s/^\v(\t)*/\=repeat(repeat(' ',&ts),strlen(submatch(0)))/g

:%s#^\v( )*#\=repeat("\t",strlen(submatch(0))/&ts).repeat(' ',strlen(submatch(0))%&ts)#g
```

(changed the separator from `/` to `#` because I needed `/` for division :P )

However... it seems you're reinventing the wheel here. `:help :retab!` and `:help 'expandtab'`. First set `tabstop` as above, then:

```
:set et | ret!

:set noet | ret!
```

The first one will change tabs to spaces; the second one, spaces to tabs, according to `tabstop`.

Comment: It seems that `:set et | ret!` and `:set noet | ret!` will replace all spaces/tabs but I only want to replace the spaces/tabs at the beginning of each line.