# insert n characters before pattern

Tags: vim

I have a text file where I want to insert 20 spaces before the string 'LABEL'. I'd like to do this in vim.

I was hoping something like `s/LABEL/ {20}LABEL/` would work. It doesn't.

This SO question is close to what I want to do, but I can't put 'LABEL' after the '=repeat()'. [Vim regex replace with n characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338794/vim-regex-replace-with-n-characters)

`%s/LABEL/\=repeat(' ',20)/g` works.

`%s/LABEL/\=repeat(' ',20)LABEL/g` gives me `E15: Invalid expression: repeat(' ',20)LABEL`

How do I get vim to evaluate `=repeat()` but not `=repeat()LABEL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `\=`, a string is expect. And `LABEL` isn't a valid string

```
%s/LABEL/\=repeat(' ',20).'LABEL'/g
```

BTW thanks to `\ze`, you don't need to repeat what is searched.

```
%s/\zeLABEL/\=repeat(' ',20)/g
```

Note that if you need to align various stuff, you could use `printf()` instead

```
%s#label1\|other label#\=printf('%20s', submatch(0))#
```